# Which classes/functions on Java 1.7 are available/unavailable for Android development?

Tags: java, android, java-7

### Background

Starting with ADT 22.6 Android finally supports writing in Java 1.7 :

- http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html
- http://tools.android.com/recent/eclipseadt226preview

It doesn't support exactly everything there, but the documentation only tells about one thing that isn't there, which is "try-with-resources", that requires using minSdk>=19 .

### The problem

I've found some classes that I can't find on Android, and wonder if there is any documentation about which classes/functions are supported or not.

As an example for a class that I can't find is [**java.nio.file.Files**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) . I wonder if that's because it's related to native code (nio).

Maybe some has changed their names/packages.

### The question

Is there any list of packages/classes/functions for things we have on Java 1.7 that can/can't be used on Android ?

Comment: Wouldn't the develop documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html be a fairly authoritative source, at least on a class-by-class basis?  Note that you can set the applicable SDK level for what those pages will display.

Comment: @ChrisStratton but it doesn't explain what's now supported (of java 1.7) that wasn't supported before.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this post explains at least the more important stuff in Java7 http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/09/java7-features.html

**edit**
List of Classes/interfaces/enums that have been created or something has change in 1.7
http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/jdk-7-new-interfaces-classes-enums-and.html

Comment: but they already talked about the features of the language, and said everything is available except for "try-with-resources", which requires API 19 and above. I asked about classes and not language features.

Comment: ok, sorry, somehow I read new features.

I found this post, at the end there is a list of al new Classes/Interfaces/Enums
http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/jdk-7-new-interfaces-classes-enums-and.html

Comment: In the list, all webpages has found the text "since 1.7", then maybe the class is not new, maybe is adding deprecated tag somewhere or just new functions, .... But all classes, methods, interfaces, enums,... that are new in 1.7 cannot be used in Android (at least before ADT 22.6)

Comment: Well, I didn't check the list , but from what I've read, "java/util/Objects" is available on Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Objects.html . so... is this list is of all 1.7 new classes? wonder how many of them are supported and how many aren't.

Comment: not all are new, Class AssertionError is from 1.4, but in 1.7 adds a new function. But with the list of the page and with the list of Android developer, you can make a first filter to reduce the new Classes that are not included at least in API 19